# Where to specify server id's using jqgrid/tabletogrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using the tableToGrid method from jqgrid to generate a grid from an existing html table. My table is defined something like this:

```
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead>
         <tr>
            <th>My Title</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
           <tr id="321"><td>Item 321</td></tr>
           <tr id="111"><td>Item 111</td></tr>
           <tr id="495"><td>Item 495</td></tr>
           ...
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The ids all come from the database and I will need them to perform updates.  When I call tableToGrid, it seems to overwrite all my ids with its own that just count from 1 to how ever many rows are in the table.  It would be nice if the onSelectRow method was passed the actual server id, but id that is not possible what is the best way to store the server id on the table, not display it and still have access to it for updates etc.

My tableToGrid call is like the following:

`tableToGrid("#myTable", {
        width:230,
        height: 500,
        onSelectRow: onSelectMethod,
        colModel: [{ name: 'MyTitle', index: 'MyTitle', sortable: false}]
    });`

Thanks.

Comment: When you mention `server id`, do you mean "the HTML element's id that is generated on the server?

Comment: How about assigning it to name attribute instead of id element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer to create jqGrid directly instead of the usage of `tableToGrid`. In the case you would has no described problems.

If you do prefer to use `tableToGrid` I can suggest you to use the following trick. [The current code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.tbltogrid.js) of `tableToGrid` can get the rowids, but it get it not from `id` attributes of the `<tr>`. Instead of that it uses `value` attribute from the radio button from the first column of the table. It will be clear on your example. You can modify your original table to the following

```
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th><th id="MyTitle">My Title</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="321"><td><input type="radio" name="sel" value="321"/></td><td>Item 321</td></tr>
    <tr id="111"><td><input type="radio" name="sel" value="111"/></td><td>Item 111</td></tr>
    <tr id="495"><td><input type="radio" name="sel" value="495"/></td><td>Item 495</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

In the example the `value` attribute of the radio button from the first column should contain the rowid. The JavaScript code can be

```
tableToGrid("#myTable", {
   width: 230,
   height: 'auto',
   onSelectRow: function (id) {
       alert(id);
   },
   colNames: ['My Title'],
   colModel: [
       { name: 'MyTitle', index: 'MyTitle', sortable: false}
   ]
});
```

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/tableToGrid_zaq.htm) will now work like you as need.

The usage of additional column with the radio button can look unneeded. I personally don't like this way. If you examine [the code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.2.0/js/grid.tbltogrid.js) of `tableToGrid` you will see that it's not complex. You can modify it so that it will get the rowids not from radio buttons but from the `id` of `<tr>` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up modifying jqrid as you suggested, it just seems wrong to add a column of radio buttons just to handle the id's.